# Uploading picture on asp.net like when you click profile picture on your Facebook account

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, image-uploading

I'm wondering how to do the change picture feature on asp.net just like the one in facebook. When you click the image a window will pop up that let's your upload your picture. Because the asp.net file upload has a text on it "Choose file". What I want is when you click the image a pop up will appear then you can navigate to upload/change picture. I need an idea / guide on how to replicate/do this in asp.net. thank you for any help/idea.

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery .

In [this](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Simple-jQuery-Modal-Popup-Window-Example-in-ASPNet.aspx) article you will see how to create Modal Popup Window using jQuery UI Modal Dialog in ASP.Net and how to display the Modal Popup Window on Button Click

And [there](https://imperavi.com/redactor/examples/uidialog/) you can find another simple jQuery UI Dialog

Hope this helped you.

Comment: thank you for this brother. :-) i'll update this post when i'm done. hahaha

Comment: i'm glad that my answer was useful.